of ... of ... structure analyze

It soon became clear that existing textbooks were inadequate
for such a course. Although there are excellent treatments
of each electronics specialty, written for the planned
sequence of a four-year engineering curriculum or for the
practicing engineer, those books that attempt to address the
whole field of electronics seem to suffer from excessive
detail (the handbook syndrome), from oversimplification
(the cookbook syndrome), or from poor balance of material.
Much of the favorite pedagogy of beginning textbooks
is quite unnecessary and, in fact, is not used by practicing
engineers, while useful circuitry and methods of analysis
in daily use by circuit designers lie hidden in application
notes, engineering journals, and hard-to-get data books. In
other words, there is a tendency among textbook writers to
represent the theory, rather than the art, of electronics.

I'm quite confused by the sentence "Much of the favorite pedagogy of beginning textbooks is quite unnecessary."
The first question
In "much of", should we consider "much of" as a phrase, or should we treat "much" as a whole and "of" as a preposition?
The second question
If we consider "much of" as a phrase, does "much of" describe or emphasize "the favorite pedagogy" or "beginning textbooks"?
If we treat "much" as a whole and "of" as a preposition, does "much" modify or emphasize "the favorite pedagogy" or "beginning textbooks"?
The third question
In "beginning textbooks," since "textbooks" is the plural form of "textbook," how should we understand the use of the plural form? Is it related to "much," or does "beginning textbooks" refer to "those books" in the "those books that attempt to address the whole field of electronics" mentioned earlier?
Thank you.
Update
Add a picture that decribes problem source from:


The structure is: [Much of [the favorite pedagogy of beginning textbooks]] is quite unnecessary. In other words: The beginning textbooks often use pedagogy that is largely (much of it) unnecessary.

I certainly wouldn't recommend texts like this for learning English! The entire turgid paragraph is just a long-winded way of saying the writer thinks "Introduction to Electronics" textbooks should focus more on putting theory into practice. Which may be a justifiable perspective, but at the end of the day a textbook is a textbook. If you want to gain practical electronics experience, pick up a soldering iron, not a textbook!

@nschneid Thank you for your structured feedback.

@FumbleFingers Thank you for your comments. Regarding electronics, I need some theoretical foundation; once I've learned the theory, I will apply it in practice because, after all, practice leads to true understanding. If we consider theory as the foundation and practice as building a house, it feels like trying to build on the beach without a solid base—without theory, the house won’t withstand the storms. Therefore, combining theory and practice is better.

@FumbleFingers A retired Chinese electronics engineer(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tCzkXv4plI) who immigrated to Canada for freedom mentioned in an interview that electronics relies heavily on practice, and I agree with most of his points. However, he also said something like, "In radio, there are so many Chinese books that I don't need to read foreign ones." I don't agree with that; I believe cutting-edge technology is conveyed through English.

@FumbleFingers Additionally, I think "the entire turgid paragraph" expresses that some books are too detailed while others are overly simplified.
Finally, I'm not just studying electronics; I'm also learning English. I feel that the future of China is bleak, with limited development opportunities, so I want to improve my English through extensive reading. Many Chinese learners spend a lot of time memorizing vocabulary, but I believe learning English through reading is more effective than rote memorization.

@FumbleFingers  One purpose of memorizing words is to read English texts, but a single word can have multiple meanings. Relying solely on memorization isn't very helpful for learning English; the downside is that you might not know the exact usage of a word when writing. In contrast, reading exposes you to various sentence structures, idioms, and the specific meanings of words in context. If we see memorizing vocabulary as mastering theory, then reading can be viewed as practice.

The text isn't meaningfully "detailed". It just repeats the same basic concept in various ways. Which is sometimes a useful thing to do if the concept being expressed is complex, but in this case it just looks like pointless verbiage to me. And there's absolutely no point in learning such incoherent waffle as the favorite pedagogy of beginning textbooks.

The paragraph is mostly good in style, coherence, and concision -- the last more at the word level than the concept level. (That is, no sentence in isolation suffers from wasted words, but the paragraph as a whole could have been condensed and expressed the same thing, if slightly less concretely.) That particular phrase is pretty poor, but the whole thing is far from being unworthy of emulation.

@FumbleFingers The text in my question comes from the preface of the first edition of The Art of Electronics. The reason you feel that the passage above is meaningless is likely because it's from the preface of the first edition of The Art of Electronics.

@FumbleFingers Many people online hold The Art of Electronics in high regard. I think if I read the book thoroughly and fully understood every sentence, not only would I learn about electronics, but more importantly, my English skills would improve significantly. In some ways, mastering English might be more important to me than mastering electronics. If I learn about electronics from this book and also enhance my English skills, it would truly be a win-win situation.

@LukeSawczak The text in my question comes from the preface of the first edition of The Art of Electronics. One of the authors is a professor at Harvard University, and the other is the director of a research institute at Harvard. Both authors are likely American, so I believe their writing style should be quite good.

I didn't find the paragraph "turgid" but concise and lucid.

Well, I don't have access to the full text of any edition of TAOE, but Google tells me Despite common opinions, TAOE is not a beginner friendly book. And obviously that's for beginners in electronics, so how much less is it a suitable text for people whose native language isn't even English! Maybe the preface was written by someone else, or maybe the actual "meat" of the book is more "accessible" (whatever that means, given what Google said).  I stand by my opinion. Don't treat it as a source text for learning English.

@FumbleFingers  First of all, thank you for your perspective. I hope you don't feel any anger regarding our conversation. My intention is that we are engaging in a friendly exchange, and I apologize if I have offended you in any way.
The Art of Electronics has now been updated to the third edition, which I am currently reading. The authors state in the preface of the third edition that it is the final edition.

@FumbleFingers  Regarding your comment about "Maybe the preface was written by someone else," I just checked the book again to confirm who wrote the preface. Since it has been updated to the third edition, there are a total of three prefaces, each written by both authors of the book.

@FumbleFingers Regarding your comment that TAOE is not a beginner-friendly book, the first paragraph of the preface of the first edition states: "This volume is intended as an electronic circuit design textbook and reference book; it begins at a level suitable for those with no previous exposure to electronics and carries the reader through to a reasonable degree of proficiency in electronic circuit design. We have used a straightforward approach to the essential ideas of circuit design, coupled with an in-depth selection of topics. We have attempted to combine the pragmatic *******"

@Tom: Not at all. I apologize if anything I wrote came across as hostile towards you. I just meant it's not a good source text for learning English. So it's unlikely to be useful to future visitors to this site, but I didn't vote to close the question on those grounds anyway. And I do appreciate that you need to work with texts that are interesting and/or of practical value - it's not helpful to always be reading stuff that's completely boring once you've figured out what it actually means.

..."the first paragraph of the preface of the first edition" looks perfectly clear and to the point to me. Are you sure what you put in that comment is written by the same person who wrote the text in the question? They seem radically different to me.

@FumbleFingers Please take a look at the evaluation of The Art of Electronics by an experienced electronic engineer from the United States. “I find that H&H tend to skip a few too many steps in their explanations, making their line of thinking hard to follow at times, even for experienced engineers. ” from Dave Tweed 's comment of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/39353/343935

Please don't keep labouring your point. Even if TAOE is the best technical book ever written on any subject, that's irrelevant to my point that what you posted in your question is not suitable text for a non-Anglophone reader to learn English.

@FumbleFingers Ok, lastly, I want to mention that there are just a few individual parts of the book that I don't fully understand, which is why I want to grasp it completely. I've written about the process of deriving a formula for which the authors only provide the conclusion. You can find it here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/722844/343935 . Before deriving this formula, I reviewed the English version of the calculus textbook again.

@FumbleFingers  Sorry,I just begin see "..."the first paragraph of the preface of the first edition" looks perfectly clear and to the point to me. Are you sure what you put in that comment is written by the same person who wrote the text in the question? They seem radically different to me."  As for "..."the first paragraph of the preface of the first edition" looks perfectly clear and to the point to me. Are you sure what you put in that comment is written by the same person who wrote the text in the question? They seem radically different to me."I have updated my question that I add picture.

@FumbleFingers  Here link https://gofile.io/d/5uiC4P is PDF version of The Art of Electronics third edition.

The syntax of "much of" is the same as "some of" and other pronominal quantifiers. "Much" is a pronoun referring to some subset of what follows.
"Much of the favorite pedagogy of beginning textbooks" means "a large portion of the pedagogy presented in beginning textbooks". Note that this is a strange use of "pedagogy", since the context makes clear that it refers metonymically to the content taught, not the methodology.
"Those" in the sense intended here is an older and somewhat literary or legal usage. It actually does not refer as a pronoun, but signals the advent of the relative clause. In modern English we would say "the": "the books that attempt to address". Note that we have a vestige of the older usage in pronominal constructions like "those of you who do X".

Thank you for your answer.

+1,  but I think you've overstated the case that those in this cataphoric construction is a fossil when you say "in modern English". This use of those hasn't fallen off; it has always been confined to situations where what is needed is the singling-out sense of the demonstrative which the lacks. Moreover, to use the {something}, when it has not been mentioned yet, could cause the reader to stumble, if only momentarily, whereas a reader familiar with this use of those would glide right along, expecting to be told by the relative clause who or what those is pointing out.

@TimR Perhaps it has different frequencies depending on side of the pond? Here in Canada, I think I would always have to mentally correct "those" to "the" (in this non-backward-referring sense, that is) to make sense of it.

@TimR I think I am familiar with the use of "those." "Those" refers to certain things.

@LukeSawczak I am Chinese. Our English teacher explained that using "the" indicates specificity. For example, when referring to the sun, since there is only one sun, we can only say "the sun," not "those sun." Additionally, "those" refers to multiple items, so it should indicate more than one.

@Tom Yes, "those" is plural (singular equivalent: "that"). "The" is used for both singular and plural. And it certainly does provide specificity (more technically definiteness), including for relative clauses: "The students who spoke to me earlier received an answer to their question."

@Tom   Yes, the "certain things" in this case are "books that attempt to address the whole field of electronics".

"Those who live in glass houses shouldn't throw stones." - another example of demonstrative + relative clause.

@nschneid Indeed -- as I noted in my answer, the pronoun in this sense is alive and well, but the determiner is désuet.

Just a side note...

Much of the favorite pedagogy of beginning textbooks is quite unnecessary and, in fact, is not used by practicing engineers, while useful circuitry and methods of analysis in daily use by circuit designers lie hidden in application notes, engineering journals, and hard-to-get data books.

I would gloss pedagogy here as "instructional material", and "favorite pedagogy" is a phrase that could be taken disparagingly to mean something like "appearing in far too many beginning textbooks (because the authors are slavishly using other textbooks as a guide or template for the inclusion or exclusion of material)".

Thank you for your answer. Is Authors in "because the authors are slavishly using ***"  refer to authors of beginning textbooks?

@Tom Who else could it refer to?  I find your question puzzling.

I apologize for not stating the question clearly. The other author I referred to is the author of the book I am currently reading, and my question comes from the preface of the first edition of The Art of Electronics. Is Authors in "because the authors are slavishly using ***" refer to authors of beginning textbooks or authors of The Art of Electronics?

@Tom  In my "expansion" of the phrase "favorite pedagogy", a phrase used by the author of The Art of Electronics, I am referring to the authors of the "beginning textbooks", those whose textbooks are being criticized.

Thank you for you explain. I see.
